# Using Casparjs to scrape government database

Tags: phantomjs, casperjs

Each Superfund site has an unique identifier (e.g. KYD980501076 ) and this can be encoded in an url to generate a results page: http://iaspub.epa.gov/enviro/efsystemquery.cerclis?fac_search=site_epa_id&fac_value=KYD980501076&fac_search_type=Beginning+With&postal_code=&location_address=&add_search_type=Beginning+With&city_name=&county_name=&state_code=&program_search=1&report=2&page_no=1&output_sql_switch=TRUE&database_type=CERCLIS

For each of the Superfund sites, I'd like to capture the name, city, state, latitude and longitude.

The code below works to find all the TDs, but I've been unable to get it to look at only the table with class "result".

Any insight is very much appreciated...

(the next steps will be to append the results to a json file)

---

```
 var casper = require('casper').create();


function getTd() {
    var td = document.querySelectorAll('TD');    

  return Array.prototype.map.call(td, function(e) {    
     return e.innerText   
  });    
}

var url = "http://iaspub.epa.gov/enviro/efsystemquery.cerclis?fac_search=site_epa_id&fac_value=KYD980501076&fac_search_type=Beginning+With&postal_code=&location_address=&add_search_type=Beginning+With&city_name=&county_name=&state_code=&program_search=1&report=2&page_no=1&output_sql_switch=TRUE&database_type=CERCLIS";

  casper.start(url);

 casper.then(function()  {
   td = this.evaluate(getTd);    
 });

 casper.run(function()  {
   this.echo(td.join('  '))
  this.exit();
});
```

Comment: Related answer can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21288883/using-casperjs-and-phantomjs-to-scrape-multiple-pages

Answer (score 0):

if you are open to trying a different solution, you can use [phantomjscloud.com](http://phantomjscloud.com) and follow the ["Pinterest to JSON" example on the docs page](http://phantomjscloud.com/site/docs.html).

if you do that, you can write your parser in jquery, and have your results returned as json.

disclaimer: i worked on phantomjscloud